# Pandas df date calculations by group

Tags: python, date, pandas

I am having a lot of trouble trying to do something that I feel is pretty simple, but I can't find a simple approach.

I have a df with the following structure:

```
Site                      category
Date                datetime64[ns]
Test_Reading                 int64

Site    Date     Test_Reading
A   2011-10-16   100
A   2011-10-20   70
A   2011-11-01   150
A   2011-11-15   110
B   2011-10-16   17
B   2011-10-17   20
B   2011-10-18   55
B   2011-10-20   155
B   2011-10-24   70
C   2011-10-01   55
C   2011-11-01   60
C   2011-12-01   110
```

I want to calculate the average number of days between test readings for each Site. I'm just having so many issues working with the date data type.

Ideally, I want to create a new df just showing the following:

```
Site   mean_lag_days
A        x
B        x
C        x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC then you want to `groupby` on 'Date' and apply a lambda where we calculate the `diff` between rows and take the `mean`:

```
In [18]:
df.groupby('Site')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())

Out[18]:
Site
A   10 days 00:00:00
B    2 days 00:00:00
C   30 days 12:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To get the final desired result:

```
In [20]:
df.groupby('Site')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).reset_index().rename(columns={'Date':'Mean_lag_days'})

Out[20]:
  Site    Mean_lag_days
0    A 10 days 00:00:00
1    B  2 days 00:00:00
2    C 30 days 12:00:00
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Simple. To deal with negative results though, would you just use abs()?

Comment: To deal with negative results  make no sense. sort before : `df.groupby('Site')['Date'].apply(sorted).apply(diff).apply(mean)`

Comment: You could use abs it should work but it does kind of alter what mean returns